# how to make logcat not vanish its its previous shown data

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, logcat

When more data is shown in logcat the upper part is vanished as new data comes in !

*I want that the logcat never vanish any data shown previously.*

How can I achieve this ?

However, I tried clicking down arrow located at the corner of logcat but no gain !

Comment: I don't use eclipse myself, so this is just a guess, but have you tried the "up arrow" to scroll up? Generally the history stays at the top, and new logging output appends at the bottom.

Comment: Write a function which writes the data into a file and call it along with logcat. This can be reused in other projects also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can never make them vanish. This answer will be helpful I guess

you can increase the number of lines that have to displayed in Logcat. Keep as much you wanna see like a million lines or so. to do this..

Go to Windows - > Preferences - > Android - > Logcat - > Maximum number of logcat message to buffer change the number of lines to your count you can view more number of lines.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse you can go to Window -> Preferences -> Android -> LogCat and there set "Maximum number of logcat messages to buffer" to a quite large number ... maybe not infinite, but still reasonable high ...

If you refer to scrolling, there is a checkbox about the Scroll Lock behaviour, too.